# Mysql join table and using not exist on same joined table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

Am trying to select join record from `TABLE_USER_MATCHES` if the `uid`, is not the one that created the match `m_from`.

My intention is to join records from `TABLE_USER_MATCHES` if it exist and it's not created by `m_from` `p1` and also ignore selecting `p1` from `TABLE_USERS` as the current user querying database.

TABLE_USERS

```
uid | u_name  
----|---------
p1  | Peter 
j1  | John
f1  | Foo
b1  | Bar
h1  | Hana
a1  | Ada
```

TABLE_USER_MATCHES

```
mid | m_from  | m_to  | m_stat
----|---------|-------|---------
mp1 | p1      | j1    | 1
mp2 | p1      | f1    | 1
mp3 | a1      | p1    | 1
```

TABLE_USER_FILES

```
fid | f_uid  | f_url   | f_path
----|--------|---------|----------
fa1 | p1     | ax.png  | gallery
fb2 | p1     | bc.png  | gallery
bc3 | j1     | cc.png  | gallery
fd4 | f1     | cx.png  | gallery
fe5 | j1     | qd.png  | gallery
```

Query

```
SELECT user.*, match.m_stat, file.f_url
FROM TABLE_USERS user

INNER JOIN TABLE_USER_FILES file 
ON file.f_uid =  user.uid
AND file.fid = (
    SELECT MAX(fid) FROM TABLE_USER_FILES
    WHERE f_uid = file.f_uid
    AND f_path = "gallery"
)

LEFT JOIN TABLE_USER_MATCHES match
ON match.m_to = "p1"
AND match.m_stat = 1

WHERE user.uid <> "p1"
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT m_stat 
    FROM TABLE_USER_MATCHES
    WHERE m_from = "p1"
)

LIMIT 0, 20
```

Expected Result

```
b1  | Bar
h1  | Hana
a1  | Ada
```

Comment: i would use cte firstly to avoid not exists which performs a way bad.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator can you show me example, that is as far I could go.

Comment: Please run `SELECT version();` to check MySQL version and post your expected result. By the way, `match` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-M), you probably should change your alias to maybe `matches` or just `mtch`?

Comment: Ya, please provide expected output @Peter

Comment: You also have this `WHERE user.u_uid <> "p1"` in your query but you `TABLE_USERS` don't have `u_uid` column. Is that suppose to be  `WHERE user.uid <> "p1"` instead? Or do you really have another column `u_uid` in the table?

Comment: @FanoFN online server '10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1', For localhost `10.4.21-MariaDB` and for `u_uid ` that was error while I was writing the question I don't have any column with `u_uid ` also the alias is used in this question is to make the question readable that not what I used in my project.

Comment: So, with the example data above, what result you expect to return?

Comment: @FanoFN  record from this 3 users `b1  | Bar, h1  | Hana, a1  | Ada` as that do not exist in match table either as 'm_from' and `p1` as `m_to` nor `m_to` and `p1` as `m_from`

Comment: Ok, from your expected result, all those 3 `uid` of `b1, h1 & a1` is not in any of the other two tables except for `TABLE_USERS`. Because if it is then the query should actually be very simple... I mean like [this simple](https://dbfiddle.uk/XQ_lONTR)

Comment: @FanoFN the sample you showed me is missing something how about add extra this to match table `('mp3','a1','p1',1);`, it only show 2 records. my concept is to select all none existing records in `match` or record other user created for me, but not the one I created for other users.

Comment: @FanoFN and `TABLE_USER_FILES ` is important for each users that is selected the only table I want to check if not exist is `TABLE_USER_MATCHES `

Comment: @FanoFN if you can maintain how my example look in joining table `TABLE_USER_FILES ` it will be easy for me to use in my project without creating errors while trying to add

Answer (score 0):

After much discussion in the comment section (until SO suggests to go *chat* ), perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT users.*, t.m_stat, t.f_url
FROM TABLE_USERS users
  LEFT JOIN
(SELECT tu.uid, tm.m_stat, tf.f_url
FROM TABLE_USERS tu
INNER JOIN TABLE_USER_FILES tf 
ON tf.f_uid =  tu.uid
  AND tf.fid = (
    SELECT MAX(fid) FROM TABLE_USER_FILES
    WHERE f_uid = tf.f_uid
    AND f_path = "gallery"
)
INNER JOIN TABLE_USER_MATCHES tm
 ON tu.uid=(CASE WHEN tu.uid != tm.m_from THEN tm.m_to ELSE tm.m_from END)
) t
ON users.uid = t.uid
WHERE t.m_stat IS NULL;
```

I've retained the most part of the first `INNER JOIN` and taking *"select all none existing records in match or record other user created for me, but not the one I created for other users"* into consideration I've added:

```
...
INNER JOIN TABLE_USER_MATCHES tm
 ON tu.uid=(CASE WHEN tu.uid != tm.m_from THEN tm.m_to ELSE tm.m_from END)
...
```

I'm not sure if I got the correct concept yet so I hope OP will comment if anything I've missed.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7L_QZxcR)

Comment: In result `f_url ` is null even when the user has a file, and `a1` the `m_stat ` is null even when it already exist in `TABLE_USER_MATCHES ` as creator

Comment: what am doing with `TABLE_USER_MATCHES `, is select one image from user gallery so all users must have image and its important go get the one from all images they uploaded. And if a user have created `TABLE_USER_MATCHES ` for me, I will also get the `m_stat`. The only thing I want to skip is the one I created for other users.

Comment: I also created this with few comment https://dbfiddle.uk/Q0v6OB4W

Comment: @FanonFN please I still have not found any solution, I appreciate your effort, will be glad if you look into it one more time

Comment: Ok, I get the condition of _"all users but me"_ only.. but doesn't that mean all other users will be shown in the result afterwards? [Like this?](https://dbfiddle.uk/yg5uFN-G)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FanoFN, in the end, i sendup using `NOT IN`, which am not sure if that is the best way to go about doing this. I will not mark this as accepted answer in case if there is better way of doing it.

[SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OTdYCEbW)

```
SET @me := 'p1';

SELECT tu.*, mt.m_stat, mt.m_from, mt.m_to, file.f_url
FROM TABLE_USERS tu

INNER JOIN TABLE_USER_FILES file 
ON file.f_uid =  tu.uid
AND file.fid = (
    SELECT MAX(fid) FROM TABLE_USER_FILES
    WHERE f_uid = file.f_uid
    AND f_path = "gallery"
)

LEFT JOIN TABLE_USER_MATCHES mt
ON mt.m_from = tu.uid
AND mt.m_stat = 1

WHERE tu.uid <> @me
AND tu.uid NOT IN (
   SELECT m_from 
   FROM TABLE_USER_MATCHES
   WHERE m_to = @me
)
AND tu.uid NOT IN (
   SELECT m_to
   FROM TABLE_USER_MATCHES
   WHERE m_from = @me
)
```

Comment: Depending on your data, `NOT IN` might perform faster than joins. I manage to replicate what you did; with joins, here > https://dbfiddle.uk/nVh_4KHW